# JS forEach method is breaking halfway through, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

This is my code. When I comment out getContentKWs it goes to 27, when I don't, it stops at 11. posts.length also says 27. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this. I put console logs everywhere and I don't see anything useful. I thought breaking a forEach method was not possible.

```
getAllPosts().then((posts) => {
    console.log("LENGTH", posts.length)
    posts
        .forEach( (post, i) => {
            console.log(i, post.title)
            getContentKWs(getTitleKWs(post.title), post.content)
        })

})
```

This is the function:

```
function getContentKWs(titleKeywords, postContent) {
    titleKeywords
        .some((keyword) => { //loop through keywords to find a good anchor text
            var keywordRegex = new RegExp("(" + keyword + ".+? ......+?) ", "i"); //make regex
            var match = keywordRegex.exec(postContent)
            if (match) {console.log("FOUND MATCH", match[0]); return match[0]} // found match
            else {console.log("NO MATCH",keyword); return false} // not found
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably throwing an exception somewhere that is then caught by the `.then()` handler.  You can probably see what is happening by adding a try/catch inside your `.forEach()`.

But, you should also always have a `.catch()` after your `.then()` and the exception will show there too.

```
getAllPosts().then((posts) => {
    console.log("LENGTH", posts.length)
    posts.forEach( (post, i) => {
        console.log(i, post.title)
        getContentKWs(getTitleKWs(post.title), post.content)
    })

}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

All standards-based `.then()` implementations automatically catch thrown exceptions and turn them into a rejected promise so if you don't want to accidentally eat/miss an exception, you should always have a `.catch()` handler somewhere in every promise chain.

---

One possibility for error in your `getContentKWs()` function is if `keyword` contains some characters that make your regex invalid when those characters aren't escaped.  The `RegExp` constructor will throw an exception if it is given an invalid regular expression.

Comment: thanks the regex catching an ' was exactly the issue and the catch worked.